# How to self host and run a Php file

Tags: php

I found a [tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-using-php-mysql-android-studio/) on-line that describes how to build an image uploader.

The author has his script available here:

http://simplifiedcoding.16mb.com/PhotoUpload/upload.php

I don't have a web site.

I would like to try the tutorial.  How do I try/test the Php files on my own computer?

Comment: Not without access to the server on which the file is hosted, no you can not.

Comment: Please clarify the server set up and what you have access to.

Comment: start by creating a file called 1.php which will contain ONLY <?php phpinfo();

Comment: run a local apache web server. find some information here: https://httpd.apache.org/

Comment: Put that file in your htdocs folder and surf to localhost/1.php. 
What do u c?

Comment: @cale-b But I just want to get an access to my upload.php(on my computer,not his)

Comment: Is your question: 'How do I set up a web site, where I can upload and share images?'

Comment: @Progrock No,i just want to run upload.php from photoupload folder

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you link to seems to require MySQL and PHP 5. You can easily run both of those on you local machine and I recommend that you do so by downloading and runnning the XAMPP installer for PHP 5 (not PHP 7):

https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

When you run the setup make sure that the following are included:

- Apache - the web server
- PHP - the (main) scripting language of the tutorial
- MySQL - the database
- phpMyAdmin - an administration tool for the database (nice to have and **if you can get it to work you have everything you need up and running**)

If you need more visual help than that, I recommend that you search for instruction videos using the words xampp, phpmyadmin and [your operating system]. Here is an example for Windos 10:

[How to Install XAMPP to your PC(OS: Windows 10)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmbvUCUyN6s)

Comment: Just to add a bit to this, you'll need to run the servers (Apache and MySQL daemons) *somewhere* -- which is just as fine on your local machine as it is on some web site "out there" on the internet. You can test and learn on your local computer without even being connected to the internet, Carl is correct that the easiest way is to install some prebuilt package that includes all the pieces working together.

Comment: @carl-von-blixen I have a xampp. So, I just need to test upload.php on my computer

Answer (score 0):

You start by understanding the setup.
From the question I assume you use Windows and you installed WAMP or XAMPP (don't ask how I know).

1. go the folder where WAMP/XAMPP was installed. Usually under program files folder
2. Look for a `www` or `htdocs` or `html` folder.
3. In that folder create a file called 1.php
4. in it put `<?php phpinfo();`
5. Turn on the WAMP/XAMPP server (when u installed it u also installed a short cut to it's controll panel)
6. surf to localhost/1.php or 172.0.0.1/1.php and make sure u see the info about your php installation.

Comment: I think it is 127.0.0.1

Comment: @itay-moav-malimovka It's work but if I put 1.php to htdocs/folder1 it won't

Comment: What do u mean it works? Where did u surf, which folders do u have under xampp/wampp?

Comment: @itay-moav-malimovka I mean that I created a php file which show "Hello world" and it worked

Comment: Show me the full content of the file, and what u saw on the screen. Did my test work, with the phpinfo() work?